# Reputation incorrectly calculated total rep for one answer and daily total

Tags: bug, android-app

I just installed the new Android App and noticed two issues:

1. An answer which received a downvote that was later removed shows an incorrect total. The total should be 75 repuation received but it shows 77 in the app. It looks like it added the two returned rep points to to final total instead of adjusting the previous total of 73 points.
2. The daily total shows 132 but should be 150. It looks it is missing reputation for two answers which are not listed with the other answers which earned me rep today. (Plus the obvious two point error mentioned above). Should the daily summary show all reputation earned for one day? Or only the last three questions/answers to receive votes?

Comment: Didn't do analysis, but something is really wrong with a reputation in the feed...